# Car won’t start despite a jump

Tags: ford, battery, jump-start, automatic-transmission

2010 Ford Fusion SEL

Been having some troubles with my car lately, following a multitude of things (including a missing undercarriage cover while it was insanely snowy, and -25C weather). It’s been having troubles starting, and I’ve jumped it probably 3 times in the last month or so. At first it would just turn over then we’d jump it, which became only clicking sounds and a jump, which has now become a clicking when the key wasn’t in the ignition at all and then went to hook it up to jump and dead silence and it wouldn’t click, turnover, start, nothing.

Do we think this is my battery or starter? Is there a way to find out without some sleeze charging me $200 just to look?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do what the sleeze would do if you invested the hundreds of thousands of dollars he has in order to diagnose and repair these problems. The first thing he would do is use the proper equipment to check your battery and be sure it's good (not reasonably sure). And then check the charging system. Followed by a thorough wire, relay and cable analysis. And when Mr. Sleeze found a problem, he would repair it, and then check for what caused this problem. It could just be worn parts due to age, or some part(s) have been damaged, maybe due to a missing undercarriage cover. Or something. Of course you can also do any of these tests yourself by using a battery tester and a multimeter. And if that didn't work you would have to check the other less likely caused like ignition switches or control modules and such. I'm reasonably sure you can find a pro out there to diagnose this for under $200.00. Some shops will waive the diagnosis fee if they do the repairs. They have a lot of expenses to cover plus they need income. It's difficult to give an hours worth of your days work for free each time someone has a problem. But yes like all businesses there are a few sleezes. Ask around for references, you will be surprised to find many reputable shops out there. Apologies for seeming defensive, but many people on this site are those who have paid a lot to attain the knowledge your looking for and are giving it to you for free.